# Javascript setInterval scoping issue

Tags: javascript, scope

I have a class I am attempting to use to manage a session on the client side, it looks like this:

```
var sessionmanager;

sessionmanager = (function() {

  sessionmanager.name = 'sessionmanager';

  function sessionmanager(timeout, action) {
    if (action != null) {
      this.action = action;
    } else {
      this.action = null;
    }
    if (timeout != null) {
      this.timeout = timeout * 60;
    } else {
      this.timeout = 0;
    }
  }

  sessionmanager.prototype.run = function() {
    return window.setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
  };

  sessionmanager.prototype.sessionExpired = function() {
    if (this.action != null) {
      window.navigate("timeout.asp");
    }
  };

  sessionmanager.prototype.setTimeout = function(timeout) {
    return this.timeout = timeout;
  };

  sessionmanager.prototype.tick = function() {
    this.timeout -= 1;
    if (this.timeout < 1) {
      return sessionExpired();
    }
  };

  return sessionmanager;

})();
```

However when I debug inside the `tick` function that is called from within the `setInterval` callback I get `this.timeout = NaN`

I am guessing I scoped something incorrectly? Help please? I am new to javascript...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `setInterval` calls the function it doesn't set the `this` value as you may expect. Calling `this.tick()` *does* set it correctly, but just passing the function and having it called in another way does not. You have to bind the `this` value to what you want:

```
setInterval(this.tick.bind(this), 1000);
```

This is available on newer browsers but there are shims available.

Also, you probably meant `this.sessionExpired()`, as that's where it's defined. `return` doesn't make much sense there since `setInterval` does not care about the return value.

Comment: You could also use the "that" trick: 
`var that = this; return setInterval(function(){ return that.tick()}, 1000)`

Comment: I ended up using the 'that' solution, as I need support for older browsers (curse you asp!) but I appreciate the help!

Comment: @missingno: True. Here it's just a matter of fixing the `this` value so I think `.bind` is a neat solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever set the timeout? You might want

```
sessionmanager.timeout=0;
```

somwhere in the class definition.

Comment: I have this.timeout = 0 in the constructor?

Comment: An instance has a `.timeout` value, not the constructor itself.

Comment: @Flying Streudel: No, your code is correct there :) The suggestion to set `sessionmanager.timeout` does not make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

In ES7 Javascript you can do the following:

```
window.setInterval(::this.tick, 1000);
```

The double colon syntax `::` is a shortcut to `.bind(this)`.