# Class variable returns undefined in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, variables

I'm new to JavaScript. Hence this problem is a bit confusing. I'm trying to simply define a counter and increment it in a class method but its not behaving as I expect it to. Specifically `console.log(this.tick_count);` prints `undefined`.

JavaScript:

```
function Game() {
    this.fps = 50;
    this.ticks = 3;
    this.current_time = (new Date).getTime();
    this.draw_object = document.getElementById('game_canvas').getContext('2d');
    this.tick_count = 0;
}

Game.prototype.update = function (time) {
    this.current_time = time;
}

Game.prototype.draw = function () {
    this.draw_object.fillRect(10, 10, 55, 50);
}

Game.prototype.run = function () {
    self.setInterval(this.tick, 1000 / (this.fps * this.tick));
}

Game.prototype.tick = function () {
    this.tick_count++;
    console.log(this.tick_count);
}

function start_game() {
    var game_object = new Game();
    game_object.run();
}
```

HTML:

```
<body onload="start_game()">
    <canvas id="game_canvas" width="1024" height="1024"></canvas>
</body>
```

Coming from a Python background I find this behavior strange. How should I set up my class variables correctly?

Comment: Where are you defining `self`? And `this` inside `setInterval` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript setInterval scoping issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333311/javascript-setinterval-scoping-issue)

Comment: Try `self.setInterval(this.tick.bind(this), 1000 / (this.fps * this.tick));` and see how it goes

Comment: @PSL That will still not work due to the lack of `self`. It is probably just a type due to his Python backgrounds.

Comment: @jshthornton lack of self what? what is self by the way.

Comment: @PSL in Python `self` is the `this` keyword-ish.

Comment: @jshthornton is this python or javascript.

Comment: @PSL This is javascript, but OP said he comes from a Python background, and he used `self` instead of this, which was probably just a typo, but it is causing issues. But to be honest, there shouldn't be a `this` there either.

Comment: @jshthornton See it working here. http://jsfiddle.net/hVjhL/ look at the console

Comment: @PSL It will work because most browsers keep a reference to window via `self` but it isn't pleasant at all as a lot of js developers use `self` as a temporary this reference.

Comment: @jshthornton yes ofcource, issue is nothing to do with with self. it is with the callback.. :)

Comment: @PSL agreed. But if you look at the top comment you can see that people are getting confused...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is what is happening.

Essentially you `tick` function is no longer running in the context of your `game_object` object. This might sound odd coming from a Python background but basically the `this` object is set to something else.

So what is it set to? Easy, the `window` object, how do we know this? Because `setInterval`'s context is the `window` object.

*Moving example as code will not format correctly below*

**Bind Example**

```
setInterval(this.tick.bind(this), 1000 / (this.fps * this.tick)); //Native (JS v1.8+)
$.proxy(this.tick, this); //jQuery
_.bind(this.tick, this); //underscore / lodash
```

**Explicit context example**

```
Game.prototype.run = function () {  
    var _this = this;  
    setInterval(function() {  
        //So what is this at the moment? window.
        //Luckily we have a reference to the old this.
        _this.tick();  
    }, 1000 / (this.fps * this.tick));  
 };
```

You can get around this two ways.

1. Bind your function to the object you want it to be on [Bind JS v1.8](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (Seeing as you're using canvas that shouldn't be an issue.
2. Invoke the method explicitly with its context. (See above)

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
setInterval(this.tick.bind(this), 1000 / (this.fps * this.tick));
// without "self"
```

Thanks to PSL and TJ Crowder

Comment: I think call is incorrect here, it will invoke the function and set the result as setInterval's calback. You should use bind.

Comment: Hmm.. not sure, i test

Comment: No, `setTimeout(this.tick.call(this), ...` will **call** `tick` immediately, and pass the return value into `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
setInterval(this.tick.bind(this), 1000 / (this.fps * this.tick));
```

As will this:

```
var self = this;
setInterval(function () {
    self.tick();
}, 1000 / (this.fps * this.tick));
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though this has been answered I think you need to understand what `this` refers to. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19068438/1641941) for more details.

If you would like to use closures instead of bind you can limit the scope by calling a function that returns a function (outside of the currently running function). This is so you can minimise the amount of variables that will be available to the closure. Sounds complicated but with a minor adjustment to your code you can do it:

```
Game.prototype.run = function () {
    //best not to define a closure here because the next variable
    //will be available to it and won't go out of scope when run
    //is finished
    var memoryEatingVar=new Array(1000000).join("hello world");;
    //note that this.tick(this) is not passing this.tick, it's invoking
    //it and the return value of this.tick is used as the callback
    //for the interval
    setInterval(this.tick(this), 1000 / (this.fps * this.tick));
}
//note the "me" variable, because the outer function Game.prototype.tick
//returns a inner function (=closure) the me variable is available in 
//the inner function even after the outer function is finished
Game.prototype.tick = function (me) {//function returning a function
  return function(){
    me.tick_count++;
    console.log(me.tick_count);
  }
}
```