# does javascript's this object refer to newly created object in the way i think

Tags: javascript, constructor

So, when we create constructor function for creating new object the new keyword does 3 things
I'am going to explain it but please correct me if I'am wrong i want to be sure I'am correct

first i will create a constructor function

```
function ObjectCreate(){
    this.a = "a";
    this.b = "b";

    ObjectCreate.prototype.show = function(){
        alert(this.a+" "+this.b);
    }
}

obj1 = new ObjectCreate();
```

now the first thing new keyword does is create new object and set its secret link to its constructor's prototype and pass it to the constructor function where now the `this` can refer to it and please note `this` does not refer to obj1 at this point because once constructor finished creating object only then it returns the newly created object to obj1 variable. i ask this question because some people say that `this` refer to the obj1 object in this case. so am i right here.

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't just try it yourself?

Comment: did you understand my question ?

Comment: its not about trying the code i am just asking something

Comment: but trying the code could probably answer your question, right?

Comment: its not about code correcting issue i am correcting my concept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example, during constructor invocation, `obj1` is undefined. Value is assigned to `obj1` variable after `ObjectCreate` function returns.

You can check yourself:

```
function ObjectCreate(){
    this.a = "a";
    this.b = "b";

    alert(obj1); // yields "undefined"
    ObjectCreate.prototype.show = function(){
        alert(this.a+" "+this.b);
    }
}

var obj1 = new ObjectCreate(); // note "var"
```

Comment: what do u say about above answer someone posted is it write because it says that objectCreate cant contain objectCreate.prototype ? is right thing

Comment: You can assign functions to object prototype in constructor, but it will be executed every time constructor is run. So, it's better to assign method functions to object's prototype once, outside constructor function.

Answer (score 2):

Your phrasing is a bit confusing, but I'll do my best. First, you should note that your curly braces are a bit off. Your code should look like this:

```
function ObjectCreate(){
   this.a = "a";
   this.b = "b";
}

ObjectCreate.prototype.show = function(){
     alert(this.a+" "+this.b);
}

obj1 = new ObjectCreate();
```

You need to define your constructor, *then* attach things to its prototype.

When you call the constructor, the `this` keyword *does* basically refer to the new object being created. This is important because, for example, you could write a constructor like:

```
function ObjectCreate(x,y){
   this.a = x*x;
   this.b = y*x+4;
}
obj1 = new ObjectCreate(10,20);
```

Here, as in all constructors, `this` refers to the instance being created (`obj1`, in this case).

I think you suggested that `this` refers to the object's prototype, but that would make `this.a` and `this.b` static variables, which would be useless in a constructor like the one here, since every time you initialized a new object you would change the vale of `this.a` and `this.b` for all previously existing objects, and that just isn't useful.

I hope that answered your question. If not, please go ahead and leave comments for further clarification.

Comment: i said that this refers to newly created object not to obj1 at the time of creation once the constructor finished executing only then the object is returned to obj1. am i right here

Comment: `obj1` *is* the newly created object. What's the difference?

Comment: You are in the process of defining it. Are you asking whether or not the object is *called* `obj1` during the creation process? That seems like a question of pure semantics.

Comment: i am  asking whether or not the object is called obj1 during the creation process?

Comment: Again, that's a question of semantics. The object doesn't *really* exist at all until the function is finished, at which point it is immediately "called" `obj1`. During the construction process, it isn't really "called" anything, because it doesn't exist as a fully formed object.

Answer (score 0):

It seems nobody mentioned that `this` refers to the `invoking object`.

```
window.sayHi=function(){
  console.log(this.name);
}
window.name="Window"
window.sayHi();//=Window

var obj={
  name:"obj"
}
obj.fn=window.sayHi;

obj.fn();//=obj
```

The code above shows that when passing functions around the `this` context will change. If you don't want that then you can pass a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) instead of the function or use [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) or [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
//closure example
obj.fn=(function(w){//w is available because the returned function is a closure
  return function(){
    w.sayHi();
  }
}(window));

obj.fn();//=Window
//using call
obj.fn.call(window);//=Window
//using apply
obj.fn.apply(window);//=Window
//using bind
var boundFn=obj.fn.bind(window);
boundFn();//=Window
```

That was when you pass a function as a parameter on another object. When you use constructor functions then `this` within the function body will refer to the object to be created.

But when you pass around it's functions it may not be:

```
var obj={
  name:"obj"
}
var Test=function(){
  this.name="Test";
}
Test.prototype.sayHi=function(){
  console.log(this.name);
};

var t=new Test();
obj.fn=t.sayHi
t.sayHi();//=Test
obj.fn();//=obj
```

This is a pitfall most people fall in when passing object instance functions to setTimeout or event handlers:

```
someButton.onclick=t.sayHi;//when button is clicked this will be the button clicked
setTimeout(t.sayHi,100);//when sayHi is executed 'this' will be window
```

To answer your question about obj1 existing within the constructor function's body; I'd say no (not in Firefox at least). I don't have a link to the specs but obj1 would be set to `this` when the constructor function returns:

```
//clean up window.t
delete window.t;
var Test=function(){
  this.name="Test";
  console.log("and window.t is:",window.t);//undefined
}
Test.prototype.sayHi=function(){
  console.log(this.name);
};

window.t=new Test();
```

More on constructor functions, prototype, inheritance, overriding and calling super [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941).