# Prototype Revealing Pattern and use of 'this' in Nested Functions or return object

Tags: javascript

I have been working with the Prototype Revealing Pattern, a trivial made up example of which is shown below.

It works fine if I return the uncommented object to expose the public functions from the prototype function as seen here [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bthere/rGPn9/)

If on the other hand I use the other nested object ( the one that is commented out ) to organize the returned public functions in a different hierarchy the functions can still be called but the instanceVar is undefined in 'this'

I understand why ( I think ) but I am not sure how to pass the correct 'this' instance, or if it's is even possible using this pattern, I am wondering if anyone knows how to accomplish this?

I have tried .call(this) in a number of ways and still can't get any joy.

```
WhoSays = function (sentence) {
    this.instanceVar = sentence;
};

WhoSays.prototype = (function () {

    var jimSays = function () {
        return 'jim says ' + this.instanceVar;
    };
    var bobSays = function () {
        return 'bob says ' + this.instanceVar;
    };

    /*return {
        says : {
            jim : jimSays,
            bob : bobSays
        }
    };*/

    return {
        jim: jimSays,
        bob: bobSays
    };

}());
```

.
UPDATE:

I don't want to modify the invocation, the caller should not need to know how to use the pattern beyond the obvious.

I am sure this is probably not a smart way to do things, namespace hierarchies might be a better way to go, but I am still interested if this is possible without using invocation to bind 'this' from the perspective of the caller e.g. who.says.jim.apply(who)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want it to work like you are trying, use it like so:

```
WhoSays = function (sentence) {
    this.instanceVar = sentence;
};

WhoSays.prototype = function () {
    var jimSays = function () {
        return 'jim says ' + this.instanceVar;
    };
    var bobSays = function () {
        return 'bob says ' + this.instanceVar;
    };

    return {
        says : {
            jim : jimSays,
            bob : bobSays
        }
    };
    /*
    return {
        jim: jimSays,
        bob: bobSays
    };*/

}();

var who = new WhoSays("works!");
console.log(who.says.jim.apply(who)); // logs "jim says works!"
```

[This tells you why this works now!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: I know I can get it to work if I modify the invocation, I guess I should have been clearer about that. I was trying to avoid the caller needing to do that.  Plus one for using apply though.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `new WhoSays().says.jim()`, the `this` is `new WhoSays().says`, not `new WhoSays()` like you want.

You could try:

```
WhoSays.prototype = (function () {
    return {
        says: function() {
            var self = this;
            return {
                jim : function() {
                    return 'jim says ' + self.instanceVar;
                },
                bob : function() {
                    return 'jim says ' + self.instanceVar;
                },
            }
        };
    };
}());
```

and then call `new WhoSays().says().jim()`.

Or use `Object.defineProperty` to define the getter `says` for notational preference.

My personal preference would be to use more conventional ways to get what you want.

Comment: I get why it doesn't work, I was trying to determine if there was some brilliant trickery to avoid changing how it was invoked, my bad for not making that more clear. I am starting to think that it's not doable without jettisoning the revealing pattern or using a .apply() etc. which means it's probably not worth pursuing.  What are the "conventional" ways that you prefer?

Comment: (1) `WhoSays.prototype.saysJim = ` and `WhoSays.prototype.saysBob = `, or (2) `WhoSays.prototype.says = ` and `Says.prototype.bob = ` and `Says.prototype.jim = `.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following code:

```
var WhoSays = function (sentence) {
  this.instanceVar = sentence;
  this.says=new Says(this);
};

var Says = function(whoRef) {
  this.whoRef=whoRef;
};
Says.prototype.jim = function () {
  return 'jim says ' + this.whoRef.instanceVar;
};
Says.prototype.bob = function () {
  return 'bob says ' + this.whoRef.instanceVar;
};

var b = new WhoSays("b");
console.log(b.says.jim());
var c = new WhoSays("c");
console.log(c.says.jim());
console.log(b.says.jim());
```

More on prototype, inheritance, overriding https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Understanding what `this` can be: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19068438/1641941

Comment: I don't think this will work because the prototype is a singleton, if you add var c = new WhoSays('c') then the single version of _me will be overwritten with c's this. A modified fiddle shows this http://jsfiddle.net/bthere/8Jpjn/ unless I am missing something in your answer.